# As...as structure

Tags: phrase-usage, comparison, comparative-constructions, as

I have a sentence like this:

> He hasn't travelled to as many places as me.
>
> He has travelled to as fewer places as me.

Are these sentence correct? and Do they have the same meaning?

Comment: **As few as** not *as fewer as*. See: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-few-as

Answer (score 1):

No, "as fewer places as me" is not correct.

The form you're looking at is not "as ... as", it's "as many ... as".

The opposite of that form is "fewer ... than".

> He has traveled to fewer places than me.

Comment: thank you. By the way, is this sentence correct? "he hasn't visited as many countries as me"

Comment: @GemBùi yes, "he hasn't visited as many countries as me" is correct.